# NullPointerException on JdbcTemplate when calling SqlServer

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I'm trying to make a query into a SqlServer, but it's always returning a NullPointerException. I don't know if it's possible that the url is incorrect (I don't think so), but here is my application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://my_database_url;databaseName=my_database_name
spring.datasource.username=my_username
spring.datasource.password=my_password
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
```

This is my controller:

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

Implementation implementation = new Implementation();

@GetMapping("/something")
public List<User> something(){
    return implementation.getSomething();
}
```

And this is my implementation class:

```
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

public List<User> getSomething(){
    return jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT * FROM users", BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(User.class));
}
```

Here is the error:

```
2022-02-07 21:22:12.207 ERROR 13476 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[. 
[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet 
[dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request 
processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] 
with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at 
com.back.project.Implementation.getSomething(Implementation.java:23) ~ 
[classes/:na]
    at com.back.project.Controller.something(Controller.java:15) ~ 
[classes/:na]
```

Thanks for your time and your help

Comment: Is the `my_database_url` really part of your url or is just there to hide the real url for this question?

Comment: is hidding the real url

Comment: Without the stack trace and corresponding code, it will be impossible for anyone to help you.

Comment: Edited: added the error

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure that the `Implementation` is a Spring bean and inject the object using `@Autowired` instead of using `new`.